# How to set color scheme for VIM in Mac Terminal?

Tags: vim, terminal, vimrc

It seems that the VIM color scheme is conflict with Mac Terminal's setting.

I want to change the highlight search color. And it's OK by setting in VIM ESC mode.
 (:hi search ctermbg=4)

However, it's not work to set in .vimrc.

Comment: Are you setting `hl Search ctermbg=4` after setting colorscheme in `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit your color scheme directly.

If it's one you downloaded from [www.vim.org](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=&script_type=color%20scheme&order_by=rating&direction=descending&search=search) it is probably located in `~/.vim/colors`, if it's one of the default color schemes it can be located in many places depending on wether you use the Apple-provided vim or another one you installed yourself. You can type `:set rtp?` to see where to find the colorscheme you are using.

Answer (score 0):

if its one downloaded by you and it doesn't work try moving it to ~/.vim-x/colors.

For some reason Mac sometimes reads that instead of ~/.vim